# Ubuntu 22.04 with varnish 7.0.3 memory issues

Tags: varnish, ubuntu-22.04, magento2.4, jemalloc

I currently have a problem with varnish 7.0.3 on ubuntu 22.04.

I'm using varnish to serve Magento frontend. Right now I have a problem with the varnish Transient storage. It keeps increasing and never goes down. It ended up consuming all the memory in my server, then swap, until the OS killed the process.

I then added a limit to the Varnish Transient memory.

The varnish.service now looks like this:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process
Environment="MALLOC_CONF=thp:never,narenas:2"

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232

# Enable this to avoid "fork failed" on reload.
TasksMax=infinity

# Maximum size of the corefile.
LimitCORE=infinity

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -a :80 \
          -p feature=+http2 \
          -p feature=+esi_ignore_other_elements \
          -p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check \
          -p feature=+esi_ignore_https \
          -p http_req_size=256k \
          -p http_resp_hdr_len=128k \
          -p http_resp_size=512k \
          -p workspace_backend=512k \
          -p workspace_client=256k \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -s Cache=malloc,2g \
          -s Transient=malloc,512m

ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My vcl looks like this:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "xxx.xx.xx.xx";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 30s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 2m;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "xx.xxx.xx.xx";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass customer, shopping cart, checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/customer" || req.url ~ "/checkout") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(health_check.php)$") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Bypass authenticated GraphQL requests without a X-Magento-Cache-Id
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if ((req.url !~ "/graphql" || !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }


    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);

        # When the frontend stops sending the auth token, make sure users stop getting results cached for logged-in users
        if (req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
            hash_data("Authorized");
        }
    }

    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }

    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
       set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if (beresp.status != 200 &&
            beresp.status != 404 &&
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

   # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
   if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
      set beresp.ttl = 0s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static|repository)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    if (!resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

My current storage usage acording to varnishstat:

```
  SMA.Cache.c_req                                                                560519          3.00          5.09          6.84          6.67          6.67
    SMA.Cache.c_bytes                                                                5.41G        26.28K        51.53K        68.42K        66.72K        66.72KSMA.Cache.c_freed                                                                5.11G        15.97K        48.68K        52.50K        74.28K        74.28KSMA.Cache.g_alloc                                                               65665          2.00           .        65647.17      65661.34      65661.34
    SMA.Cache.g_bytes                                                              307.05M        10.30K          .          306.92M       307.09M       307.09MSMA.Cache.g_space                                                                1.70G       -10.30K          .            1.70G         1.70G         1.70GSMA.Transient.c_req                                                            909978         14.98          8.26          8.48         11.18         11.18
    SMA.Transient.c_fail                                                             3579          0.00          0.03          0.56          1.64          1.64
    SMA.Transient.c_bytes                                                            4.32G       110.74K        41.16K        57.47K        68.57K        68.57KSMA.Transient.c_freed                                                            3.82G       104.61K        36.40K        54.04K        70.60K        70.60KSMA.Transient.g_alloc                                                           94503          1.00           .        94495.50      94490.31      94490.31
    SMA.Transient.g_bytes                                                          511.89M         6.13K          .          511.84M       511.81M       511.81M
    SMA.Transient.g_space                                                          116.70K        -6.13K          .          161.41K       191.47K       191.47K
```

My process is now consuming 1.3g according to "top" command. I don't know where the overhead in memory is coming from.

Another problem is that I don't see the transient memory every going down, and it reaches the limit of the defined total transient memory, according to the varnishstat. If I put a bigger limit it reaches it in the space of a day and never goes down. Once it reaches the limit I start having 503 errors on the pages are uncachable.

Also the total memory of the varnish process ends up being bigger that the limits I put on it like I describe above, sometimes consuming the server memory, then causing the OS to kill the process.

If I take out the transient memory limit it as the same behaviour. It just consumes all the server memory and ends up using swap, until it reaches its limit.

At that point the OS kills the varnish process.

Here is an example of a request that goes into the transient malloc:

```
*   << Request  >> 1738503
-   Begin          req 1738414 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1692807381.618637 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1692807381.618637 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       xxx.xx.xx.xxx 61744 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /pt/amasty_customform/form/sessiondata/?form_id=117&product_id=0
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-64e630d5-44639bc57601a91f12db85e0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
-   ReqHeader      accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
-   ReqHeader      x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: cors
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: empty
-   ReqHeader      referer: https://example.com/pt/catalogsearch/result/?q=luis
-   ReqHeader      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      cookie: _fw_crm_v=a04c9d30-7217-4f38-8899-a4a9369be22f; _fbp=fb.1.1661177844022.1077852103; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=c8dbd677-372a-4e20-b19f-199a83c67d08; _hjSessionUser_1906806=eyJpZCI6Ijk4MjQxYzk2LTVhMzItNTZmMy1hNGQ0LWFkNDk3MDE2ZjQ1NSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xx.xx.xxx, xxx.xx.xx.xxx
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /pt/amasty_customform/form/sessiondata/?form_id=117&product_id=0
-   ReqUnset       accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   HitMiss        1738502 119.935997
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 1738504 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1692807381.675756 0.057118 0.057118
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 16:16:21 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/json
-   RespHeader     Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=8g2ec2gn6n2n9sqk5h6oqpie4q; expires=Wed, 23-Aug-2023 17:16:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   RespHeader     Set-Cookie: form_key=iPsTGv3W97OSSV5l; expires=Wed, 23-Aug-2023 17:16:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Expires: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 16:16:21 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Security-Policy: font-src *.gstatic.com data: *.fontawesome.com *.twitter.com *.typekit.net *.twimg.com *.trustedshops.com *.googleapis.com *.amazonaws.com *.klarnacdn.net data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-actio
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 1738503
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/7.0)
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS
-   RespUnset      Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 16:16:21 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 1738503
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/7.0)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1692807381.675787 0.057150 0.000031
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 46
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1692807381.675807 0.057169 0.000019
-   ReqAcct        2813 0 2813 6040 46 6086
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 1738504
--  Begin          bereq 1738503 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1692807381.618703 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /pt/amasty_customform/form/sessiondata/?form_id=117&product_id=0
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    Host: example.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-64e630d5-44639bc57601a91f12db85e0
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
--  BereqHeader    accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
--  BereqHeader    x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: cors
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: empty
--  BereqHeader    referer: https://example.com/pt/catalogsearch/result/?q=luis
--  BereqHeader    accept-language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    cookie: _fw_crm_v=a04c9d30-7217-4f38-8899-a4a9369be22f; _fbp=fb.1.1661177844022.1077852103; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=c8dbd677-372a-4e20-b19f-199a83c67d08; _hjSessionUser_1906806=eyJpZCI6Ijk4MjQxYzk2LTVhMzItNTZmMy1hNGQ0LWFkNDk3MDE2ZjQ1NSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xx.xx.xxx, xxx.xx.xx.xxx
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 1738504
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1692807381.618718 0.000015 0.000015
--  Timestamp      Connected: 1692807381.619308 0.000604 0.000589
--  BackendOpen    33 default xxx.xx.xx.xxx 80 xxx.xx.xx.xxx 55692 connect
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1692807381.619323 0.000619 0.000015
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1692807381.675691 0.056987 0.056367
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2023 16:16:21 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: application/json
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=8g2ec2gn6n2n9sqk5h6oqpie4q; expires=Wed, 23-Aug-2023 17:16:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=iPsTGv3W97OSSV5l; expires=Wed, 23-Aug-2023 17:16:21 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
--  BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
--  BerespHeader   Expires: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 16:16:21 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Security-Policy: font-src *.gstatic.com data: *.fontawesome.com *.twitter.com *.typekit.net *.twimg.com *.trustedshops.com *.googleapis.com *.amazonaws.com *.klarnacdn.net data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-actio
--  BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
--  BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
--  BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  TTL            RFC 0 10 0 1692807382 1692807382 1692807381 1661271381 0 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 0 259200 0 1692807382 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1692807382 cacheable
--  TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1692807382 uncacheable
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1692807381.675716 0.057012 0.000025
--  Filters         testgunzip
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     2 chunked stream
--  Gzip           u F - 46 31 80 80 304
--  BackendClose   33 default recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1692807381.675759 0.057056 0.000043
--  Length         46
--  BereqAcct      2848 0 2848 6039 46 6085
--  End
```

Don't know if there is something wrong with the configurations above or it is a problem with the libjemalloc2 version "libjemalloc2/jammy,now 5.2.1-4ubuntu1" and need somehow to upgrade the jemalloc2 to 5.3.0.

If so how can I upgrade to that version, since everything was installed by the apt package manager?

Edited:

I increased the transient memory to 1GB now. The transient memory is still increasing but I noticed 1 detail:

```
SMA.Cache.c_req                                                                244078          0.00          5.72          2.70          3.83          3.83
SMA.Cache.c_bytes                                                                2.27G         0.00         55.74K        27.39K        35.41K        35.41K
SMA.Cache.c_freed                                                                1.82G         0.00         44.69K         7.80K        13.66K        13.66KSMA.Cache.g_alloc                                                               73357          0.00           .        73337.70      73282.31      73282.31
SMA.Cache.g_bytes                                                              460.15M         0.00           .          459.98M       459.52M       459.52M
SMA.Cache.g_space                                                                1.25G         0.00           .            1.25G         1.25G         1.25G
SMA.Transient.c_req                                                            384452          2.99          9.01          3.27          3.89          3.89
SMA.Transient.c_bytes                                                            1.91G        21.93K        47.01K        23.70K        28.57K        28.57K
SMA.Transient.c_freed                                                            1.66G        15.99K        40.90K        18.81K        23.93K        23.93K
SMA.Transient.g_alloc                                                           44521          1.00           .        44513.66      44497.95      44497.95
SMA.Transient.g_bytes                                                          254.50M         5.93K          .          254.46M       254.36M       254.36M
SMA.Transient.g_space                                                          769.50M        -5.93K          .          769.54M       769.64M       769.64M
```

If you look at SMA.Transient.c_bytes 21.93K is comming in (at a specific time), so I think it should release the same amound of data (not sure about this) but SMA.Transient.c_freed is just releasing 15.99K. That is why Transient memory keeps increasing.

Can someone tell me why this could be happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It is not a problem of memory leak. The problem is that the magento provided vcl file was an issue if you don't have a machine with a lot of memory.

The issue is here:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
       set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if (beresp.status != 200 &&
            beresp.status != 404 &&
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

   # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
   if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
      set beresp.ttl = 0s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

    return (deliver);
}
```

The problem is that all uncached requests will still stay in a grace period of 3 days. That makes the transient memory increase a lot since each uncached request remains 120s + 3d (grace period).

My solution was to change the grace period to 0 seconds when the request is "uncached".

```
sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 2h;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
       set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if (beresp.status != 200 &&
            beresp.status != 404 &&
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.grace = 0s;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.grace = 0s;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

   # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
   if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
      set beresp.ttl = 0s;
      set beresp.grace = 0s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }
   return (deliver);
}
```

I also decrease the global grace period to 2h since I don't need it to be 3 days.

To understand how the object lifetime in varnish works check this link:
https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/object-lifetime/

This is a really good explanation to understand the problem.